# How to change column value?

Tags: r

I am a novice of R. Thanks for your help in advance.

I newly created the new data frame by joinning 3 data frames as in the image below.
[image]

After merging the dfs, I tried to rename the column names to get the values for over 70's. But there are still 3 different column names as below.

How can I merging the values for 70 and over 70's?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shared the data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) nor did you share the code that resulted in the above output but looking at the image here is an attempt which might work for you.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(age = ifelse(age %in% c('70+', '70-79', '80+'), '70+', age)) %>%
  summarise(across(`2020`:`2017`, sum, na.rm = TRUE)) -> result

result
```

You can write the above in base R as :

```
aggregate(.~age, transform(df, 
            age = ifelse(age %in% c('70+', '70-79', '80+'), '70+', age)),
            sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: It works as perfect as expected. Thank you. Sorry I didn't upload the dataframe as I totally forgot.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>%
    group_by(age = case_when(age %in% c("70+", "70-79", "80+") ~ "70+", 
            TRUE ~ age)) %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```